# flink taskmanager failing with OOM

Tags: java, apache-flink, flink-streaming

have a flink job listening to kafka topic, all the job does is listen to kafka and insert the message to elastic search. The job keeps failing with one of the task managers going OOM.

I am using flink docker in kubernetes with 3gb memory. But i see failures in taskmanager logs . I am not using any special features just listen and write to elastic.

```
Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "I/O dispatcher 2945"

Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "pool-1170-thread-1"

Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "I/O dispatcher 5441"

Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "I/O dispatcher 2467"

Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "pool-3944-thread-1"

Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "pool-2651-thread-1"
```

Comment: I followed https://github.com/apache/flink/tree/release-1.10/flink-container/docker to spin up the cluster

Comment: Did you change the settings of memory configurations? Do you use state backends? Could you provide a [heap dump](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/monitoring/application_profiling.html#analyzing-out-of-memory-problems)?

Comment: i am not using state backends.. as i am not managing any state. simple read and write thats it.. if this is success we thought of adding more content. read from kafka write to elasticsearch. since this is a container..donot know how to get jvm heap

Comment: State naturally arises through the use of operators, but it shouldn't be so much as to cause any OOM. What kind of parallelism are you using? Could you halve it and try again?
Also regarding heap dump, can you run your job without a container? (You can also [dump inside a container](http://poor-developer.blogspot.com/2019/11/java-heapdump-analysis-in-docker.html) but you then download the dump from your image)

Comment: sure i will run it without containers and see. also will try to a memory dum in the contaienrs...will reply once done.. thanks for the guidence

Comment: found the issue.... after many days there is a connection leak with es and after fixing it it runs smoothly now.. thanks arvid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Thanks Arvid, we did dig through the logs and found ES is leaking a connection code issue after fixing it and using rocksDB as backend state we are running smooth with incremental check pointing turned ON.